# CSS overflow issue with featured slider

Tags: html, css, overflow

On this website http://rwl.rwlwater.com/ I have a small issue... I added overflow: hidden to the featured slider div, the pictures were showing up stacked if the javascript was enabled or the user had a slow internet connection..

But now I have another problem.. The description had a little thing positioned outside the slider and it's hidden now...If I add overflow-x: visible it adds the scroll bar and that's not what I want. I want the description to be fully visible, but the overflow-y to be hidden.

If you want to see the fully thing, just use Firebug and remove overflow: hidden on the slider and the description thing will show up again...If you add the overflow, it will hide. I need to have it without any scroll bar. I tried overflow-x: visible and auto but it only adds a scroll bar at the bottom and that doesn't work for me, I need the original effect.

Comment: "if the javascript was enabled" -- you meant "disabled", right?

Comment: If you don't mind measking, how did you get the shadow behind the slider?

Comment: @Mark that's simply a semi-transparent PNG file in the background.

Comment: Well it's nice it gives the slider a nice 3-d appearance (even though I know it's really not)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need `overflow: hidden` for browsers with disabled JavaScript support, then you can keep the rule in the code, but reset it to `visible` using JavaScript as soon as the document is ready -- this way it won't affect JavaScript-enabled browsers.

Example:

```
$(function () {
    $('#slides').css('overflow', 'visible');
});
```

Comment: No, this is not what I want... Because they show up stacked even for a slow internet connection and that's not what I want. I want only one picture visible even if it takes some time to load the page, just like it is now, but with the description fully visible.

Comment: Have you tried it? I think the solution I proposed might actually fix the slow connection problem -- I assume it's caused by a delay between the images being loaded and JavaScript kicking in and enabling the slider features. With this solution, `overflow: hidden` will be effective until JS begins executing, so it should keep the images in order.